# How to disappear an alert div after display it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have an alert div as follows,

```
<div style="width: 12%;" ng-if="final_data.status =='confirmed'" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="left" ng-cloak>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;confirmed</div>
```

The div will pop-up when the status becomes confirmed. How can I auto hide the div after displaying it? Any idea guys?

Comment: Have a button that sets final_data.status to not confirmed?

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to remove it:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('alert');
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
},500);
```

Comment: It's got an Ng-if - despite he's tags assigned. I assume it's an angularjs question really.

Comment: Or you can add a close button in that status message. On click, you can remove element.

Comment: Douwe, am using angularJS. So how can i use this function? ng-hide?

Comment: Hi Shaun, you are absolutely correct, am using angjs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change

```
ng-if
```

to

```
ng-hide
```

And then use timeout on javascript viewmodel/controller:

```
setTimeout(function{
    final_data.status = 'confirmed' ;
}, 1000);
```

And this on html:

```
<div style="width: 12%;" ng-hide="final_data.status=='confirmed'" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="left" ng-cloak> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;confirmed</div>
```

Happy to Help you

Answer (score 0):

You can watch, when status gets changed to "confirmed" and do something.

```
<div style="width: 12%;" ng-show="canShow" ng-if="final_data.status =='confirmed'" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="left" ng-cloak>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;confirmed</div>


$scope.canShow = true;
$scope.$watch('final_data.status', function (newValue, oldValue)) {
    if(newValue === 'confirmed') {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.canShow = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Am bit new to AngJS. How can I pass this to html?

Comment: You need to add this watch section in your controller. Thats all. If you change status after 1 min, it will hide the div automatically.

Comment: It is the only way, you can act once the status changed to confirmed.

Comment: Please do rememeber(as you are new to AngularJS), you have to inject $timeout on your controller. You can refer docs to do so.